# Update SQL variable of Type xml with value in varchar variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have one xml as

```
declare @EventBodyXml xml
set @EventBodyXml ='
                <LocationCopied xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/someName" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <Location xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/someAnotherName">
                <a:Name>SomeLocationName</a:Name></Location>
                </LocationCopied>'
```

I am retrieving location name in @uName variable using below query
`declare @uName nvarchar(100)
set @uName=@EventBodyXml.query(
'declare default element namespace  "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/someName";
declare namespace a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/someAnotherName";
/LocationCopied/Location/a:Name').value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') ;`

Then doing some manipulation with @uName and now want to update @EventBodyXml with new @uName value.

```
@uName='SomeNewUpdatedValue'
```

I have tried something like this below

```
    set @EventBodyXml.modify('replace value of (
                declare default element namespace "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SCS.Domain.BusinessObjectManagement.Contract.EventModel";
                declare namespace a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SCS.Domain.BusinessObjectManagement.Contract.ViewModel";
                /LocationCopied/Location/a:Name/text() ) with  sql:variable("@uName") ') ;
```

But I am getting error  like

> Msg 2205, Level 16, State 1, Line 27 XQuery [modify()]: ")" was
>   expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you  just miss location of namespace before `REPLACE`

```
declare @EventBodyXml xml
set @EventBodyXml ='
                <LocationCopied xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/someName" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <Location xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/someAnotherName">
                <a:Name>SomeLocationName</a:Name></Location>
                </LocationCopied>'


declare @uName nvarchar(100)
set @uName=@EventBodyXml.query(
'declare default element namespace  "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/someName";
declare namespace a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/someAnotherName";
/LocationCopied/Location/a:Name').value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') ;

select @uName

set @EventBodyXml.modify('
declare default element namespace "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/someName";
declare namespace a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/someAnotherName";
replace value of (/LocationCopied/Location/a:Name/text())[1]
with sql:variable("@uName")
');

print cast(@EventBodyXml as nvarchar(max))
```

i have found one interesting thing during this problem you have to define `default namespace` which you are using in your `XML` variable

```
declare @EventBodyXml xml
set @EventBodyXml ='
                <LocationCopied  xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/someName" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <Location xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/someAnotherName">
                <a:Name>XXXXXXXXXXXX</a:Name></Location>
                </LocationCopied>'


declare @uName nvarchar(100)
set @uName='yyyyyyyyyyyyy'


set @EventBodyXml.modify('
  declare default element namespace "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/someName";
  declare namespace a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/someAnotherName";
  replace value of (/LocationCopied/Location/a:Name/text())[1]
  with sql:variable("@uName")
');

print cast(@EventBodyXml as nvarchar(max))
```

Comment: @Roshan glad it helps you :)